# Debug remote pyc/pyo files

Tags: python, debugging

I try to debug `pyc`/`pyo` files, but fail because of  Non-ASCII characters (`'\xd1'`).
Pudb does run against the `py` files, but due to limitations in the specific environment, i need to run it on `pyo`/`pyc` files.

Did anyone face this issue? do you have any idea / solution?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I received an answer on the PuDB mailing list and was told that one can't debug pyc/pyo files using PuDB which is a source-level debugger.

So i wonder if someone here faced a similar situation (debugging pyc/pyo files) and have the right tool for the mission. A colleague of mine uses WingIDE for that, so he runs the debugger on py files in his IDE against remote pyc files. Are there known non-IDE solutions?